# UnCaught Reference: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I need to keep track of counter while using ng-repeat module. 
I have a counter set before the ng-repeat code as :

```
<script type="text/javascript"  var counter = 0;></script>

Then come my important code : 
<div class= "col-md-4"  ng-repeat="coffeedata in coffecataloge">
<img id="product-images" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:30px;width:50px;height:50px"/>
<script type="text/javascript" >
counter += 1;
</script>
</div>
```

Now the thing is I get an error when I am trying to increment the value of counter saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: counter is not defined"

Any idea how can I achieve my task ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not valid html, nor is it javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  var counter = 0;></script>
```

You should put the `var counter = 0;` inside the `script` tag, same as you did with the second script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var counter = 0;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marko. That worked fine. 
Also, the counter gets incremented only ONCE inside the ng-repeat loop. Can you explain what is wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Because this script executes before the `ng-repeat` does it's job and the script isn't executed again. Also, you should never do things this way, especially since you're using angular. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you should be doing this inside controller or at least, calling a function on the controller that does something with the counter. Also, the first counter shouldn't be a global variable either. But all this is a whole new problem and is outside of the scope of this question.